# Qt QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent member access to incomplete type 'QMouseEvent' Error

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, incomplete-type

I am getting an error I don't know how to resolve.

I created a class `CustomScene` that inherits `QGraphicsScene` and I want to override the mouse functions in this class.

I am trying to create a rectangle on the scene by dragging and dropping and when even I try to get the position of the mouse using `event->pos().x()` I get `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` member access to incomplete type `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`

```
#ifndef CUSTOMSCENE_H
#define CUSTOMSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <customrectitem.h>


class CustomScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CustomScene(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
 protected:
     void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;
     void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;
     void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;


};

#endif // CUSTOMSCENE_H
```

```
#include "customscene.h"
#include <QDebug>

CustomScene::CustomScene(QObject *parent)
   : QGraphicsScene{parent}
{

}

void CustomScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{

qDebug() << "the scene know that the mouse is pressed";

 QGraphicsRectItem* rect = new QGraphicsRectItem(event->pos().x(),event->pos.y(),100,100); 
 //the line of the error
 this->addItem(rect);

}

void CustomScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
qDebug() << "the scene know that the mouse is moving";
}

void CustomScene::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
qDebug() << "the scene know that the mouse is released";
}
```

Comment: Did you try `#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "member access to incomplete type" usually happens when you are trying to work with a type (i.e. call a method) that has only been declared using [forward declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class).

In this case `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` is forward declared in [qgraphicsscene.h](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsscene.h.html#75). The actual declaration is in [qgraphicssceneevent.h](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicssceneevent.h.html#QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent). To use that just put

```
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
```

in your source. Note that this is also explicitly stated in the first paragraph of [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html).